# Installation of scoop times out

Tags: powershell, ipv6, scoop

I want to install [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) on a laptop on which I do not have administrator rights. I use the following commands in PowerShell:

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser
PS> iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
At line:1 char:1
+ iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I believe this is due to it using IPv6 by default instead of IPv4:

```
PS> ping get.scoop.sh
Pinging d19x8hxthvia8.cloudfront.net [2600:9000:2002:7200:1f:b80:d400:93a1] with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
PS> ping -4 get.scoop.sh
Pinging d19x8hxthvia8.cloudfront.net [52.85.245.136] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 52.85.245.136: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=246
Reply from 52.85.245.136: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=246
```

How can I force the **iex** command to use IPv4 instead of IPv6?

Comment: Note that generally the OS will only prefer IPv6 if it sees that IPv6 is _available_ to begin with. It's possible that your router has partial configuration, e.g. advertising an address prefix but not a default route.

Comment: Normally IPv6 should be working. I now noticed I can't ping Google either as it defaults to IPv6. I'll investigate whether this is due to a laptop misconfiguration or a router misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following working solution:

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser
PS> $wc = new-object net.webclient
PS> $wc.headers.add('host', 'get.scoop.sh')
PS> iex $wc.downloadstring('https://52.85.245.136')
Initializing...
Downloading...
Extracting...
Creating shim...
Adding ~\scoop\shims to your path.
Scoop was installed successfully!
Type 'scoop help' for instructions.
```